# When does a finite ring become a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

I'm relatively new to ring theory so this is probably a simple question.

Its easy to see that a finite ring that is commutative and has no-zero divisors (i.e. an integral domain) must have multiplicative inverses.

I am wondering if we can rearrange these properties and always get implication or produce finite rings with only 2 of the above properties.

Explicitly my questions are:

1) Does a finite ring that is commutative with multiplicative inverses always have no-zero divisors?
(EDIT: this one is pretty easy too, let $xy=0$ and assume $x\neq 0$. then $x^{-1}xy=x^{-1}0$. Hence, $y=0$ as desired.)

2) Is a finite ring that has multiplicative inverses and no zero divisors always commutative?

If these are actually simple exercises, I'd just like a hint to get started with the proof or any counterexamples.

Thanks :)

Comment: You might want to look at: http://www.springer.com/engineering/electronics/book/978-1-4020-7039-6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**HINT**  1) If $\;\rm R\;$ is finite then $\;\rm x\to r\:x\;$ is onto iff 1-1, so $\;\rm R\;$ is a field iff $\;\rm R\;$ is a domain.

2) is [Wedderburn's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: Thanks! I see (1) now. Just say x,y are in R and then do xy=0. WLOG assume x not 0. then x has an inverse so (x^-1)xy=(x^-1)0, hence  y=0.

I think I need some more time with Weddernburn's little theorem, since I haven't really heard of a lot of the terms used in the link.

Answer (score 2):

Des MacHale has a nice and simple answer to the question *When is a finite ring a field?*

**Theorem:** Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a finite non-zero ring with the property that if $a$ and $b$ in $R$ satisfy $ab=0$, then either $a=0$ or $b=0$. Then $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a field.

MacHale demonstrates that 1) and 2) are particular cases of this theorem. The article is published online by the Irish Mathematical Society [here](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/ims/bull37/bull37_35-38.pdf)

Comment: It would be better to post the proof directly here, or at least to outline it. The link is only to the first page, which only states the theorem.

Comment: It is not true, the link contains the complete article. Specifically, it is Theorem 3, whose proof is on pages 36 and 37.

Comment: This theorem is more general in that it does not assume the ring is commutative like Number does in his question.